# Instantiating a nib object to present in a view

Tags: iphone

I have a LegendViewController that shows a legend.  Originally, I just plopped an UIImageView in there.  However now, we need a few legends and I want to reuse the LegendViewController.  So I created a new initializer:

```
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view withNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So now this works assuming I pass in a UIView object.  For one of my legends, I was wondering if I could load a .xib into my view controller without an image or a UIView object.  I have a very simple legend where I just want some color coded squares (UIViews with colors), and some text (UILabels).  I can create this in a standalone .xib file, but I wasn't sure how I could load it into my LegendViewController.  I've got so far as:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HealthLegend" bundle:nil];
```

where HealthLegend is my standalone .xib file with my data.  Or can this not be done and I need to either create an image in some drawing program, or draw the code manually in drawRect?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference guide

> When you create an UINib object using the contents of a nib file, the
>   object loads the object graph in the referenced nib file, but it does
>   not yet unarchive it. To unarchive all of the nib data and thus truly
>   instantiate the nib your application calls the
>   instantiateWithOwner:options: method on the UINib object
>
> UINib object can provide a significant performance improvement

So I guess you want something like:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HealthLegend" bundle:nil];
NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load a nib like this

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"HealthLegend"
                                                                          owner:nil
                                                                        options:nil];
// Assuming you only have one root object in your nib
[self.view addSubview:[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Change the owner to the appropriate object depending on what you set the `File's Owner` to in the nib (if that's even required - sounds like you have a static view so it may not be)